# What is Andy Burnham's accent? Is it Liverpool, Manchester or elsewhere?

Tags: accent

Andy Burnham was born and brought up in a working-class Liverpool family, supports Everton and makes the point that after Cambridge he returned to his home city; though he does sit for a constituency (Leigh), which is closer to Manchester than to Liverpool.

Although he has a clear Lancashire accent, it does not seem to me to include the classic Scouse (Liverpool) features. He sounds nothing like Paul McCartney, Wayne Rooney nor Steve Gerrard.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBfoS6e6pFg) is Steve Gerrard - Scouse

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCm7F8vVAD8) is Ringo Starr  - Scouse

[These](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8vIpRCfGLs) are Gary Neville and Paul Scholes, former Manchester United & England footballers talking to Adam Caterall      - All Mancs.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk7J9WrARWE) is Jimmy Anderson - Lancashire and England cricketer   -  Burnley?.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mLNl7GUXlI) is Andy Burnham  - ?

If there is a Henry Higgins out there please could you identify whether Burnham is a Scouser, a Manc, or what?

Comment: According to his Wikipedia biography, Burnham was brought up and educated about halfway between Liverpool and Manchester.

Comment: @StoneyB He was brought up in Newton le Willows, which I would have thought was well within the Scouse accent catchment. Moreover he identifies with Liverpool to the extent of being an Everton supporter. He is also (and as an American, you may not see the significance of this) a Roman Catholic. That would definitely predispose him more to Liverpool than to Manchester. There may be something in the geography. Or perhaps his Dutch wife has had an influence on him.

Comment: What accent is associated with the way Burnham says: *us, london, country, up, money, number, done, but, budget, just, vulnerable, government, come, and cuts*?

Comment: @TimRomano Well it is clearly a north-west England accent - there is no doubt whatever about that. If I knew nothing about him, and somebody asked - where does that guy come from? the answer would be clearly 'Lancashire'. But it doesn't have those special features that you hear in the Scouse accent - shirt pronounced sheert; were pronounced 'weere' etc. There is also an intonation difference between Liverpool and the rest of Lancashire.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Where are you Edwin? You must have a view on this.

Comment: Sorry, but while his is not nearly as broad an accent as other examples, Andy Burnham **does** have a Liverpool accent. It's almost certainly been watered down by Cambridge and London [and possibly deliberately, having to fit in]. It's not a Lancashire accent -- I work with someone with a Lancashire accent -- and that and Cheshire are all distinguishable.

Comment: That said, why he doesn't have a strong accent, or "what happened", can only be a matter of conjecture. Can you edit the question so that it is not "primarily opinion-based"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I was in Chester the other day (which is closer to Liverpool than it is to Manchester) and the predominant accent seemed to lean to Liverpool. But I think you are right that Burnham's has been 'watered down'. At least he didn't make the dreadful mistake of Roy Jenkins, who when he went to Oxford converted from a South Wales lilt to one of 'marked RP' ('cloth' pronounced 'clawth' etc). There are some who think his resulting excessively posh accent cost him the leadership of the Labour Party and hence being PM.

Comment: A poster on [this](http://".skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=1033053&page=48) forum who who appears to be from Liverpool himself sneers at London journalists who "think he's a scouser despite his Culcheth accent". And a poster [here](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/telegraphuk/andy_burnham_says_hes_not_part_of_the_metropolitan_elite_so_what_about_this_picture_then/oldest/) remarks that "He isn't a Scouser. He's from Culceth. Which is like saying Alderley Edge is Salford." . . .

Comment: And a poster [here](http://vote-2012.proboards.com/thread/2464?page=2) says "he was born in Aintree but his family moved out to Lowton, which is a new housing development in between Leigh and Warrington - its in the Leigh constituency - so in fact he did return to the seat where he was a teenager. Its actually why his accent isn't really 'Scouse' but more typical of his constituency." All these folks seem to hear the same difference you do.

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, I think you have hit the nail on the head. Having listened to Burnham again I now find I disagree with Andrew Leach. Though I perhaps agree to the extent that Burnham's accent has been watered-down - it is not an *eh by-gum* Lancashire either. I've looked up Culcheth and it looks a slightly up-market village.

Comment: Oh, I haven't hit anything on the head--just plucked the needle from the Google haystack!

Comment: I can detect a very faint scouse accent on some words, e.g. *south* (0.30); *country* (31.0) and *better bet* (1.03) but you have to listen carefully to pinpoint them, and I was only able to do this because I heard the previous two scouse recordings.  It's a hybrid accent, because I can hear words whose pronunciation wouldn't be amiss in the south.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Clearly you have a highly tuned ear for this kind of thing. I have no posted some Manchester voices as well as Liverpool ones, and you will be struck by how different the accents are, for two places so close together. Does that help you in any way? I would also be interested to know whether two Italian cities so close geographically would produce such markedly different accents.

Comment: Yes, accents vary tremendously but between *regions*, less so between cities, in my experience. Obviously the differences become more marked as you move further away. The Tuscan accent is very different form the Emilian accent, although both regions confine with one another http://www.belmontprimary.iinet.net.au/images/Italian/ItalianRegionsMap.jpg

Comment: The Lancashire accent for me is really hard to identify. I don't know anyone from that area, whereas I have had some contact with Liverpudlians and to a much lesser degree with Mancunians.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Mancunian is closer to a general Lancashire accent, such as is spoken in the outlying towns such as Bolton, Wigan, Blackburn etc. Of course, in South Manchester nowadays there has been such an influx of south Asian, Middle Eastern, Chinese etc that you will hear every accent under the sun. But Adam Catterall in the clip I posted has a quintessential Lancashire accent.

Comment: I really like listening to accents, and I think you'd be better off asking **what accent(s)** does  Burnham have rather than asking "why". You would have to ask the man in person if he had chosen to smooth the edges of his childhood accent, if it was different from today.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes I have changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Having lived in and around Liverpool in the past but not being a native, I thought Andy Burnham sounded more Mancunian than Liverpudlian.  Maybe his parents were from Manchester?  He's definitely a 'northerner.'

Comment: I think you are right. I cannot agree with Andrew Leach that it is a Liverpool accent (despite Burnham being an Everton supporter). He was actually born in Aintree but apparently grew up in Culcheth, which looks to be an up-market village (has properties costing in the £700 to £800k region) nearer to Manchester than Liverpool. I sense that his parents were probably Scousers, however. And he is a Roman Catholic, which tends to identify him with Liverpool - though there are plenty of RC's in Manchester too.

Answer (score 0):

Chasley is mostley correct but only lived in Culcheth untill after his education. He then moved to a small village called Lowton where he became involved in politics. I used to see him in the Hare and hounds pub but he didn't drink alcohol he drank soft drinks and read the Times and independent newspapers.
Lowton is half way between Liverpool and Manchester.